# Mail.app iOS: "Remind Me" about sent message

Tags: ios, mail.app

I sent an email that I want to follow up on. "Remind Me" is only available in the inbox, not in sent items. How can I have mail remind me to follow up?

Answer (score 0):

Mail.app will remind you to follow up automatically (unless you opted out)!

[Apple](https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/reply-to-forward-or-follow-up-on-emails-mlhlp1010/mac):

> **Get reminded to follow up on emails with no response**
>
> If you send a message and don’t receive a response in 3 days, the sent email automatically resurfaces to the top of your inbox to help you remember to follow up.
>
> - To ignore a follow-up suggestion, swipe right on the message in the message list.
> - To turn this feature on or off, choose Mail > Settings, click General, then select or deselect the checkbox next to “Enable message follow up suggestions.”

Comment: I'm not sure this will work with auto-replies though (e.g. "case created" may be interpreted as "answered").